# Enable previous command cycling at ftp prompt

Tags: command-history, ftp

Currently on pressing arrow keys or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd>, I see characters like

```
ftp> ^[[A
ftp> ^[[B
ftp> ^P
ftp> ^N
```

I would like to know, how to configure the ftp prompt so that I am able to view the previous commands just like we do on other shells (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> in bash or arrow keys)

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to use an ftp client which implements command history.

Comment: like [`ncftp`](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)

Comment: or use something like `rlwrap`

Comment: Or [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru) (it's probably in your distribution already).